# Como hacer o poner un boton en mi app como el de la pantalla de inicio ese que se desliza

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Necesito colocar un botón similar al de la pantalla de inicio que se desliza con el dedo para desbloquear los móviles.

Me refiero concretamente a este:

[image: Slider, deslizar para desbloquear]

Comment: Podrías agregar una imagen o al menos tu código que has tratado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buscando por [Android-Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/free) no he sabido encontrar nada.

Me vienen en cabeza dos métodos.
Uno usar drag-drop pero no ser si se puede restringir la zona en mover el elemento y hasta que no llegue al destino B no lance el evento.

El segundo es usar el componente SeekBar, personalizarlo un poco y en el evento `OnSeekBarChangeListener` saber % que se está moviendo, si se deja de pulsar, puede volver hacia al inicio.

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/myseek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

y en java

```
sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            if (seekBar.getProgress() > 95) {

            } else {

                seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if(progress>95){
                seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.load_img1));
            }

        }
    });
```

Solución extraída de [How to make slide to unlock button in android (en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910226/how-to-make-slide-to-unlock-button-in-android)

Comment: Con esto logro lo que quiero casi en su totalidad, solo faltaria de dar un poco de diseño para q tome forma de boton